# Gradle 7 task ':distTar' is a duplicate but no duplicate handling strategy has been set

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I have upgraded from gradle 5 to gradle 7 and now receive the following error. ':distTar' is a duplicate but no duplicate handling strategy has been set.

In the build.gradle file I originally was receiving the error : "Execution failed for task ':bootJar'. is a duplicate but no duplicate handling strategy has been set." To make this error go away I used the following in my build.gradle :

```
tasks.withType(Jar).all {
    duplicatesStrategy 'exclude'
}
```

This then gives me the following error that I am asking for help on. The task distTar for me I believe is coming from my plugin 'application', but I can't find a way to reference that task to add a duplicatesStrategy to resolve the issue.

Any help to solve this error is appreciated!
Thanks!

Answer (score 9):

You need to use regular parenthesis...

```
tasks.withType(Tar){
    duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.EXCLUDE
}

tasks.withType(Zip){
    duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.EXCLUDE
}
```

Comment: The regular parentheses did the trick in my case, thank you!!!

Answer (score 4):

Tried this seemed to work out fine.

```
tasks.withType<Tar> {
    duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.EXCLUDE
}

tasks.withType<Zip>{
    duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.EXCLUDE
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In Kotlin DSL :-

```
val distTar by tasks.getting(Tar::class) {
    duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.EXCLUDE
}
```

For Groovy DSL - Check Previous Answers.

Answer (score 0):

This one seems to be a decent catch all as Copy, Zip, and Tar all extend it:

```
tasks.withType(AbstractCopyTask).configureEach {
    if(getDuplicatesStrategy() == DuplicatesStrategy.INCLUDE) {
        setDuplicatesStrategy(DuplicatesStrategy.EXCLUDE)
    }
}
```

Oddly enough gradle already sets them as default INCLUDE but there must be some flag (that also gets set from running setDuplicatesStrategy) that also needs to be set since it errors out without setting it this way.