# How to integrate duplicate handling strategy in application plugin

Tags: gradle, build.gradle

I am using the application plugin in one of my projects. After upgrading to Gradle 7.x I got the failure:

```
        Execution failed for task ':xyz:distTar'.
        > Entry xyz-1.0/lib/jaxb-core-3.0.1.jar is a duplicate but no duplicate handling strategy has been set. Please refer to https://docs.gradle.org/7.3.3/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Copy.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.Copy:duplicatesStrategy for details.
```

I found a stack overflow post related to that [Gradle 7 task ':distTar' is a duplicate but no duplicate...](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69134136/gradle-7-task-disttar-is-a-duplicate-but-no-duplicate-handling-strategy-has-b). But the recommendation to incorporate...

```
tasks.withType<Tar> {
   duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.EXCLUDE
}

tasks.withType<Zip>{
   duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.EXCLUDE
}
```

did not work out for. It ended in the failure:

```
A problem occurred evaluating project ':integration-test'.
> Could not get unknown property 'withType' for task set of type org.gradle.api.internal.tasks.DefaultTaskContainer.
```

My build.gradle looks basically like this...

```
apply plugin: 'java'
apply plugin: 'application'

version = '1.0'
sourceCompatibility = 11
targetCompatibility = 11

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
}

dependencies {
    implementation(
        ...
    )
}

application {
    mainClassName = 'a.b.c.XYZ'
}
```

Any idea?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Shouldn't that be with regular parenthesis?

```
tasks.withType(Tar) {
   duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.EXCLUDE
}
```

or:

```
tasks.withType(Tar.class).configureEach {
    duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.EXCLUDE
}
```

Answer (score 2):

For spring boot I found this to be working:

```
tasks.withType(Tar).configureEach {
    duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.INCLUDE
}

tasks.withType(BootJar).configureEach {
    duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.INCLUDE
}

tasks.withType(Zip).configureEach {
    duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.INCLUDE
}
```

Comment: I updated the following part "tasks.withType(BootJar)..." as  -> "tasks.withType(Jar)...." and it works great. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Note that if you are using the `installDist` task (rather than [distTar](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/application_plugin.html#sec:application_tasks)) inside the application plugin you will need to set:

```
installDist {
    ...
    duplicatesStrategy = DuplicatesStrategy.INCLUDE

    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar issue (not exactly the same):

> Execution failed for task ':processApiTestResources'.
>
> > Entry junit-platform.properties is a duplicate but no duplicate handling strategy has been set. Please refer to
> > https://docs.gradle.org/8.6/dsl/org.gradle.api.tasks.Copy.html#org.gradle.api.tasks.Copy:duplicatesStrategy
> > for details.

Adding the below lines to build.gradle, helped fixing the issue though:

```
rootProject.tasks.named("processApiTestResources") {
    duplicatesStrategy = 'include'
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Mine got fixed with this.

```js
tasks.withType(Copy) {
    duplicatesStrategy = 'exclude'
}
```